# Use opened file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I've got 2 programs, and in one i'm opening a file to read and from the other one i'm trying to read from file :

first  program

```
fd = open("test.txt",O_RDONLY);
printf("%d\n",fd);
while(1);
```

second program :

```
char sir[100];
int fd, result;
scanf("%d",&fd);
rez = read(fd,((void*)sir), 2);
```

In the second program i read what i printed in first program. Why this code doesn't work and how can i read from that file descriptor from program nr 2?

Comment: `fd = scanf("%d",&fd);` is overwriting the value of  `fd` that `scanf()` obtained, with the function return value. If the `scanf()` call was successful, `fd` ends up as `1`, the number of fields converted. If unsuccessful, `fd==0`.

Comment: wrong, that fd is in prorgram nr 2 not in prgram nr 1

Comment: excuse me? I have pointed out a fault in your code.

Comment: srry, was my fault, i edited that mistake :D

Comment: Ahh, so now you've changed the question. What is the question? I don't understand what you are asking in the title ... and now you've changed the title too! I don't believe this is actually your code, now.

Comment: i've got 2 programs and one open a file and get a fd, and the other one use that fd to read from file, but this it doesn't work :D

Comment: You can't just copy the `fd` value of an opened file in one program to `fd` in another and expect it to work.

Comment: @user3052078 A file descriptor is an operating system resource connected to the process that created it (or inherited it from its parent process), and it's identified by a number, an int. That int is only of significance to the process that created the file descritor, you cannot transfer a file descriptor to another process by just reading/writing a number from one process to anohter.

Answer (score 3):

File descriptors are unique to the process. Also you need to write to the file descriptor.

Comment: so, i should use system or exec to call second program from first one ?

Comment: thanks man, i used execvp from first program to open the second one and now it work :D

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems:

- `fd = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY)` opens the file for reading.  If I understand what you are trying to do, you want to create the file and open it for writing.  That would be `fd = open("test.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY)`.
- `printf("%d\n",fd)` displays the value of the file handle.  While that might be useful for debugging, I think you want something which writes to the file handle.  `write (fd, "hello", 5)` is closer to that.
- `while(1);` is an infinite CPU busy loop.  This is not very useful.

Similarly the second program has issues:

- `fd = scanf("%d",&fd)` is peculiar.  I think you want to open the file just written, no?  Instead, `fd = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY)`.
- With that corrected, the program can then read the content into the variable `read (fd, sir, sizeof sir)`.

See if those help you.

If you are not primarily working with binary data in the files, the `fopen()` and `fprintf()` library calls are more convenient.